# What is the background about the tattoo around Jellal's eye?

Tags: fairy-tail

[image]

Why does Jellal have the red tattoo around his eye? Where did it come from? Is there anything special about the shape of the markings?

Comment: Incidentally, it's the same tattoo with [Sieghart from Rave Master](http://ravemaster.wikia.com/wiki/Sieghart)

Comment: @Darjeeling Not incidentally as the mangaka of Rave Master is the same as Fairy Tail, that is Mashima Hiro.

Comment: @AyaseEri I'm fully aware of that

Comment: `Sieg and Jellal are both based on same character named Magic Illusion from Mashima's one-shot 'Magician', with both appearances and mastery of magic.` - [Rave Master Wikia](http://ravemaster.wikia.com/wiki/Sieghart)

Answer (score 3):

Fun fact, this is actually a reference to Hiro Mashima's (the author of Fairy Tail) other series "Rave Master." In that show, there is a character named Seigrain, who has a tattoo over his eye, which is the same as Jellal's. This character also looks very similar to Jellal's.

Sometimes Mashima sneaks in stuff from Rave Master. Such as Plue, who he describes as his own pet who he can use in whatever he likes. So, that's probably why Mashima put it in there.

Comment: So it's only there as an Easter Egg? There is no in-story explanation for it?

Comment: None so far. Also note Jellal infiltrated the council using the same name, Siegrain.

Comment: Add a Rave Master picture of Siegrain!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's before the tower of heaven happened. He was in a village or something and they did a ceremony for the most powerful child (most magical energy) and they gave that child a special mark to note that he is the strongest; maybe they were going to use him to fight wars (until he was taken by the people at the tower of heaven).

I know that it's also a reference to Rave Master which was made by Hiro Mashima, the author of Fairy Tail.

Answer (score 1):

The ceremony thing isn't possible, its likely that he was born with the markings and my evidence is mystogan/prince jellal of edolas as it's a parallel universe where everyone is opposite.